# Error al añadir FK

Tags: sql

Estoy teniendo problemas con tres FK. Es una relación N:N que apunta a sus PK . Todas tienen el mismo tipo (SMALLINT)

Esta es la tabla dónde tengo que poner esas FK

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS result(
municipalityID SMALLINT,
districtID     SMALLINT,
sectionID      SMALLINT,
tableID        SMALLINT,
partyID        SMALLINT,
provinceID     SMALLINT, 
votes          INTEGER,
```

Tabla que tiene las PK y quiero que sean FK.

```
introducir el código aquí
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tableElection ( 
municipalityID  SMALLINT,
districtID      SMALLINT,
sectionID         SMALLINT,
tablesID        SMALLINT,
possibleVotes   INTEGER,
totalVotes      INTEGER,
nullVotes       INTEGER,
blankVotes      INTEGER,
pollingstationID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_tableElection PRIMARY KEY 
(municipalityID,districtID,sectionID,tablesID), 
CONSTRAINT fk_tableElection_pollingstation FOREIGN KEY 
(pollingstationID) 
                         REFERENCES pollingstation(ID) 
                               ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

);
```

Sólo he tenido problemas con esas tres FK. Las estoy añadiendo con esta sentencia

```
ALTER TABLE result
ADD FOREIGN KEY (districtID) REFERENCES tableElection (districtID);


ALTER TABLE result
ADD FOREIGN KEY (sectionID) REFERENCES tableElection (ID);


ALTER TABLE result
ADD FOREIGN KEY (tableID) REFERENCES tableElection(tableID);
```

Y me sale un "ERROR CODE 1215 CANNOT ADD FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT" . ¿Porque me da este error si tengo la tabla creada y el tipo de dato coincide?

Gracias!!!

Comment: sería ideal que mostraras la siguiente tabla pollingstation y checar el nombre del id de esa tabla

Comment: Si ya hay datos en las tablas, puede que actualmente alguno quedase *huérfano* si se crease la restricción, por lo cual la misma no se puede crear. De todos modos intenta crearlas una por una. En todas las que falle, deberás garantizar que la integridad referencial se cumple antes de crear la nueva restricción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no he podido entender cuales son las dos tablas que tienen la relación muchos a muchos.

pero veo que la tabla **tableElection** tiene una PRIMARY KEY compuesta por 3 columnas por lo que la tabla con la que la estas relacionando, (la que posee el FOREIGN KEY), debe tener una FOREIGN KEY compuesta. algo así como esto:

```
    ALTER TABLE result
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (districtID, sectionID, tableID) REFERENCES tableElection (districtID, ID, tableID);
```

Comment: Me corrijo, tableElection tiene una PRIMARY KEY de 4 columnas!, si o si (must!) si tableElection es la tabla maesto, y la tabla result es la tabla detalle, result debe tener estas mismas 4 columnas, NO SOLO 3, y hacer la FOREIGN KEY compuesta que hice arriba, pero de 4!

Comment: Exacto, como dice Stiven, cuando agregas una FK a una tabla, debes traer la PK completa de la tabla maestra. En este caso, es prácticamente copiar la definición de la PK de tableElection, a la definición de FK en result (4 campos).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has salvado :)